# DataTable Column Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
function getalluserrollforviewtracker() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/mobitelprogress/Auserrole',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
            displayalltrackernames(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#managerselectuserrole').html("<tr><td colspan='5'class='text-center' style='color:red'>System Error.</td></tr>");
        }
    });
}

function displayalltrackernames(data) {
    var rowData = "";
    if (data.length === 0) {
        $('#managerselectuserrole')
                .html("<tr><td colspan='5'class='text-center' style='color:red'>no any User Role done yet </td></tr>");
    } else {
        $.each(data, function (x, tDataJson) {
            rowData += "<tr>"
                    + "<td>" + (x + 1) + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + tDataJson.userRole + "</td>"
                    + "<td><i class='ion-checkmark-circled'></i></td>"
                    + "<td align='center'><input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-info '  value='info' onclick='loadtrackerpage(" + JSON.stringify(tDataJson.userRole) + ");' /></td>"
                    + "</tr>";
        });
        $('#managerselectuserrole').html(rowData);
    }
}
```

I create ajax call for get `json` data in my databases. Then I displat data using above javascript method. My table body's id is `id=managerselectuserrole` like that. So I can set data into my table. But my total data rows are about 100. Therefore I want to use `DataTable Column Filter` method. How I apply above method for my above code.

Comment: RTFM : https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html